# Google Charts Rendering Empty Chart addRows() Errror

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I have a  JavaScript array which looks like this:

```
[
{x: "Station a", y: -77.33333333333333},
{x: "Station b", y: -19},
{x: "Station c", y: 9.492537313432836},
...
]
```

I wish to create a bar chart using Google Charts. The following code gives me an empty chart... there are no bars. The x-value is supposed to be the label and the y-value creates the bar in the chart.
Do I have to manually push the array values into the data table? If so, how would this be done?
This is an excerpt of the code, n being the JavaScript array:

```
// load necessary google charts libraries
google.charts.load("visualization", "1", {'packages':["corechart"]});
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});

function plot1() {
        var dataPoints = []; // temporary array
        var n = []; // final array with data
        
        var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        chartData.addColumn('string', 'Station');
        chartData.addColumn('number', 'Arrival');
        
        n.forEach(function (row) {
            chartData.addRow([row.x, row.y]);
        });
        
        url = // localhost url with json data
        
        // push json data to array
        function addData(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < data[i].delays.length; j++) {
                    dataPoints.push({
                        x: data[i].delays[j].Station,
                        y: data[i].delays[j].Arrival
                    });
                }
            }
            
            // filter "no information" values from array
            values = ["no information"]
            dataPoints = dataPoints.filter(item => !values.includes(item.y));
            
            // eliminate duplicates of x and get average of the y values
            const map = new Map();
            dataPoints.forEach(({ x, y }) => {
                const [total, count] = map.get(x) ?? [null, 0];
                map.set(x, [(total ?? 0) + parseInt(y), count + 1]);
            });
            
            // final array with data in desired format
            n = [...map].map(([k, v]) => ({ x: k, y: v[0] / v[1] }));
            
            console.log(n);
        }
        
        $.getJSON(url, addData);

        var options = {
            width: 700,
            legend: { position: 'none' },
            chart: {
            title: 'Verteilung der Verspätungen bei Ankunft (in Sekunden)'},
            axes: {
                x: {
                0: { side: 'top', label: 'Stationen'} // Top x-axis.
                }
            },
            bar: { groupWidth: "90%" }
                };
        
        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('plot1'));
        chart.draw(chartData, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
    };

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(plot1);
```

In the HTML header I have specified

```
<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src = "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrayToDataTable` expects a simple two-dimensional array, with intrinsic values only.
with the column headings as the first row.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Station', 'Arrival'],
  ['Station a', -77.33333333333333],
  ['Station b', -19],
]);
```

you can find the details [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.arraytodatatable).

it returns the full data table, so there is no need to use `addColumn` afterwards.

-- OR --

you can create a blank data table, then add the columns and rows.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Station');
data.addColumn('number', 'Arrival');

n.forEach(function (row) {
  data.addRow([row.x, row.y]);
});
```

**EDIT**

`$.getJSON` runs asynchronously. so you have to wait until it has finished,
before the data will be available.

move the loop to the end of `addData`.
then draw the chart once the data is ready.

note: you don't need the first `load` statement.

see following snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['bar']
}).then(plot1);

function plot1() {
    var dataPoints = []; // temporary array
    var n = []; // final array with data

    var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    chartData.addColumn('string', 'Station');
    chartData.addColumn('number', 'Arrival');

    url = // localhost url with json data

    // push json data to array
    function addData(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < data[i].delays.length; j++) {
                dataPoints.push({
                    x: data[i].delays[j].Station,
                    y: data[i].delays[j].Arrival
                });
            }
        }

        // filter "no information" values from array
        values = ["no information"]
        dataPoints = dataPoints.filter(item => !values.includes(item.y));

        // eliminate duplicates of x and get average of the y values
        const map = new Map();
        dataPoints.forEach(({ x, y }) => {
            const [total, count] = map.get(x) ?? [null, 0];
            map.set(x, [(total ?? 0) + parseInt(y), count + 1]);
        });

        // final array with data in desired format
        n = [...map].map(([k, v]) => ({ x: k, y: v[0] / v[1] }));

        console.log(n);

        n.forEach(function (row) {
            chartData.addRow([row.x, row.y]);
        });


        var options = {
            width: 700,
            legend: { position: 'none' },
            chart: {
            title: 'Verteilung der Verspätungen bei Ankunft (in Sekunden)'},
            axes: {
                x: {
                0: { side: 'top', label: 'Stationen'} // Top x-axis.
                }
            },
            bar: { groupWidth: "90%" }
                };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('plot1'));
        chart.draw(chartData, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

    }

    $.getJSON(url, addData);

};
```

Comment: thanks for your help! I used the loop example you gave since i have to add data dynamically... unfortunately it throws an error stating:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Data for arrayToDataTable is not an array
Do you perhaps need the rest of the code to understand why this is happening? I could edit my post

Comment: note the code above, after OR. there is no `arrayToDataTable` -- it's just `DataTable` --> `new google.visualization.DataTable();`

Comment: `arrayToDataTable` is a static method used to create a `DataTable`, in the second example, we create a blank `DataTable`.

Comment: ah okay thanks i changed that part... no more errors but still a blank chart :(

Comment: if you could edit the question with the latest code, I'll take a look...

Comment: please include all google charts code, including the `load` statement...

Comment: done. thanks so much for taking the time to look at it and help me

Comment: oh my goodness it works! thanks so much i have sitting forever trying to figure it out, you're amazing

Comment: cheers! glad to help. note: you are using what google calls a _Material_ chart. there are several options that are not supported by _Material_ charts. see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)